# footer disappear on some pages frequently

Tags: css, footer

I have a problem with my footer that keeps is disapearing. I am using blade theme. On other pages news articles it is showing. Does anybody know what could be the problem? my site is http://www.jacobscapital.co.za

Comment: Remove position:fixed from footer 
#grve-footer.grve-fixed-footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}